# AnyLogic model time only from 06:00-22:00

Tags: time, anylogic

is there a way that my model runs only for 16 hours a day instead of 24 hours?
My goal is to skip the time between 22:00 and 06:00.

I tried to change the model times properties -> nothing found to change

Another idea is that an event occurs every evening and changes the model time to the next morning, but I could not find a function to change the model time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply exclude some time. You can:

- fast forward through time at 10pm (but model events will still be simulated if you have them --> your responsibility to not have anything happen)
- switch to your own time mode where you convert `time()` steps into your frame of reference (i.e. your model is in `HOUR` time units and after the first 22 hours, you assume implicitly that the next hour would be 6am again)
- just model 16 hrs in 1 model run but re-run that several times via a (freerun) parameter-variation experiment (where each run is a new day) and you accumulate results via the experiment